# QuerySet select_related not working when overriding get_queryset methd on generic ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

When overriding the `get_queryset` method on a generic `ListView`, the `select_related()` method, does not have any effect on the `queryset`, making n+1 sql calls on template loop:

models.py:

```
class Bulding(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('properties:building_detail', args=[str(self.ph.pk), str(self.id)])        ...


class Property(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('properties:property_detail', args=[str(self.ph.pk), str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class PropertyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PHViewMixin, ListView):
    model = Property

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(ph=self.kwargs['some_kw']).select_related('building')
```

property_list.html:

```
...
{% for p in object_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ p.building }}</td><td><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ p.name }}</a></td>>...</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
...
```

If I remove the `{{p.building}}` I get 3 sql calls, vs 47 the way it is right now, checked with django-debug-toolbar.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Eric

Comment: What was your intention for using select_related() method? select_related() method is the way to retrieve everything at once with one query when it has FK relationship.

Comment: Exactly, that was, but I'm getting a new db call on the loop for each Property object when accessing the Building foreignkey

Comment: can you try select_related('building__name') instead?

Comment: Does not work either, checked. Name is not a foreignkey on Building.

Comment: Does `PHViewMixin` also override `get_queryset`?

Comment: No, PHViewMixin doesn't override get_queryset

Comment: What does the `__str__` method and `get_absolute_url` look like for `Building`? Is it attempting to use a foreign key property there?

Comment: Update it on question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the foreignkey to `PH` in the `select_related` method call because it is used in `get_absolute_url` method:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Property.objects.filter(ph=self.kwargs['ph_pk']).select_related('building', 'ph')
```

Thanks for your comments